# Scapy Error "No module named all'

Tags: python, module, scapy

I am using

`from scapy.all import *` , but then appear error "No module named all".

`from scapy import all` , didn`t fix the problem.

Why system can`t find those module?

Comment: did you try 'from scapy  import *'

Comment: Yes, but it didn`t help. Because when I use it and try make the packet, system can`t find IP or Ethernet features

Comment: Which version are you using? There was no all module in some old versions.

Comment: Does just running `scapy` on the command line work?

Comment: Yes, it works from command line